# How can ActionListener sends the result of the process back to the JTextArea

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield, gettext, jtextarea

My question is a bit complicated and as my program is a bit big, I can't put it all here.  Anyway, here is the description of the problem: The program has a JTextField, and JTextArea.  When the user searches for a word, by getText, and addActionListener it sends the entered word to the action listener, in action listener it search for the result and then print it out in command line. But I want the action listener sends it back to the previous class where there is a JTextArea. To show the result of the search in the text area.

So now in the search part, there is a system.print.out() code, but I should replace something to send it back.

So any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String result = search(textField.getText());
    textArea.append(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Your code seems correct, but obviously I dont have the search method, so what method should I replace?  Any previous method that I enter, it keep giving errors that the method does not exist and wants to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's no way to answer this question without knowing more about the structure of your program other than to say that the class that holds the JTextArea needs to have a public method that allows you to pass a String in and then it will append the String to the JTextArea. It's all about making sure that the classes that need references have valid references to the correct objects so that they can call the appropriate methods on those objects when needed. How your ActionListener gets the reference to the class holding the JTextArea again depends completely on the structure of your program.

Answer (score 0):

If your actionListener is a completely new class you'll have to start by giving it the base class (that is the class containing the guiElements) as a parameter (preferably at initialization) then the actionListener can call a method of this base class when the event is triggered. 
 if you declare the actionlistener in this way

```
guielement.addsomeactionlistener(new actionlistener{ implementable methods});
```

you can simply call a method of the base class without giving your base class at initialisation.